# What is the best way to refresh a page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know what is the best way to refresh the page after typing.

For example, I press a button that modifies the name of a product, how can I do that from the moment I validate my modification, the changes appear immediately, without having to manually refresh the browser page.

I saw some example with react-router, doing a redirect or using 'history.push', I also saw with the 'window.location.reload (false)' but it doesn't feel right because you can 'see' that the page refresh (yes you don't manually refresh but ... maybe there is something better to do)

Comment: `history.push` is the best way I feel.

Comment: Why don't you use your state? React will check your state changes, if there are any, it will re-render itself.

Comment: @KevinYobeth Maybe I did it wrong but I already try and it didn't work. I was doing a const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState() and after the onClick setRefresh({}}. It's not like that ?

Comment: `useState()` create a state in your application. What this state contain is your data. You can bind your input to the state of your application, and react will.. well react, to the data changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#state-hook) hooks of react to view the changes without refreshing the window.

In every state change, which means the change of value on the given state, react automagically rerender to show the latest data.

```
const [productName, setProductName] = useState('');

cosnt handleButtonClick = (name) => setProductName(name)

return (
<>
 Production Name: {productName} // Product name changes on every button click. 
 <button onClick={() => handlebuttonClick(dynamicallySendRequiredDataFromHere)}> Change product name </button>
<>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the best way is to not refresh the page at all.

Specially if you are using React. Every piece of data that you display on your UI is supposed to be stored in some kind of state. Even if that data should somehow be validated asynchronously (I think this is your case), once done, you should trigger a state change that will cause the interested components to re-render and display the new information.

Comment: Yeah and I'm currently using state but do you have an example  of how to re-render ? I think it's with " ? " and " : "

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your requirement actually.

If you want to reload the page to get something which can only be achieved by reloading then use

`window.location.reload()`

If you want to reload just to get the data then make the API call and connect your component with the state that gets the value after the API call

If you want to maintain the history stack the use

`history.push()`

If you dont want to maintain the history stack the use

`history.replace()`

Some fancy times when you want to set cookie or storage to your page but dont want to refresh current page you can use `window.open` with the origin and `target`

`window.open(window.location.origin, '_blank')`